# Confluence Connection Refused When Connecting to Jira

Tags: jira, confluence

First, I have setup Jira on a box and I am installing Confluence on the same box. During the setup of Confluence after it installs, I am trying to connect to Jira to pull in my user groups. In the URL location for jira, I am putting in `http://jira-qa.mycompany.com` and I am receiving the following error.

```
Connection refused. Check if an instance of JIRA 4.3 or later is running on the given url.
```

I am confused because these two instances live on the same box and are on the same lifecycle: QA. Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure JIRA so that it will allow your Confluence instance to connect to it?

Did you follow the steps as described in the ["Allowing Other Applications to Connect to JIRA for User Management" documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/allowing-other-applications-to-connect-to-jira-for-user-management-720412342.html)?